# c# .net access parent obj

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using .net c# MVC controller to query database for many of my projects.  Every time i create a new controller, I find myself having to rewrite some of the same function for the new controller hence, I thought about writing a basic controller to handle some of the basic task that I use in all my controller (e.g., run a query and run json).

In my controller, I reference the basic controller like this.

```
namespace myWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class esrcController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /esrc/
        string db = "esrc-";
        basicController BasicController = new basicController();


        public string test()
        {
            return "test" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
        }
        public string getCodingException()
        {

            return @"{""data"":" + BasicController.getDataNconvertToJSON(
                "select * from z_codingexception order by nc_key",
                BasicController.getEnviroment(db)) + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

in my `BasicController`, the `getEnviroment` looks at the url to determine the environment hence I need access to :

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] and Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"].ToString().ToLower();
```

but Request is null in this controller, I only have access to request in the main controller.  How do I reference httpRequest from basic controller?

Comment: Why not put it in a separate class entirely? And why aren't you following standard .NET naming conventions?

Comment: one idea you can pass this controllercontext into constructor parameter for base class, also what is the purposes of this setup?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit new at this, what do you mean by separate class entirely?  I will look into the .NET naming conventions

Comment: @chungtinhlakho [here is a link to the capitalization conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you instantiate a new instance of a controller, doesn't mean you'll have access to the context.

One option is to create an abstract base controller that all of your other controlers would inherhit from. You'll then have access to the specific objects like `Request`

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

**Your Controller**

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
 protected void myMethod()
 {
  // you have access to Request here
 }
}

public class MyController : MyBaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("my/getstuff")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStuff() 
    {
       // do stuff
       base.myMethod();
       return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, get this "Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'MyBaseController' is less accessible than class 'MyControllerController'", if I changed MyBaseController to public, the error goes away but get a 404 if I try to go to it http://localhost:61792/My/GetStuff .  thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming you're using web api, you'll need to setup the appropriate routing in order for the method to be called. see updated answer

Comment: see the attributes i put on the web api method

Answer (score -1):

Create an action filter and add it as an attribute to that class. Within the action filter yuo wil have access to the `Request` object. If you override the `OnActionExecuting` function, the functionality in your filter will be executed before your controller.

Create a custom filter

```
public class CustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      //DO STUFF WITH YOUR REQUEST OBJECT HERE..
    }
}
```

Add the filter as an attribute to your controller

```
[CustomAttribute]
public class esrcController : Controller
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address what is asked, action filter is a very useful feature, but I don't see how it applies here, would you mind expanding?

Comment: It gets to the heart of what he's trying to do: execute functionality on every controller and have access to the `Request` object.

Comment: Sorry to disagree with you. This just seems like you are showing off the knowledge of filters.

Comment: That's just insulting. I have no desire to show off.

Comment: No intention to offend you. Filters don't add a lot of value when all you do is just execute some code. Write it explicitly and use a helper if you want it to be short.

They are very useful when you want to morph the request, inject extra data or set things up front for the controller method.

Just because a pattern exists it does not mean you want to apply it and further obscure the code. Although I don't appreciate a use of base classes are a code reuse pattern because they are an abuse of OOP, it is a pragmatic approach.

Comment: I did look a lot at actions for this scenario, and they don't fit very well and even worse as you start using more than one, you might get into ordering and cost to run issue as well as obscuring the code that is being called (e.g. you can't F12 into them)

Comment: Whether you use a helper class or a filter, the code is going to be obscured more. I don't know why you feel that you need to explain your opinion. And a helper class is not going to help with F12 debugging.

Comment: I see your point. You are right about F12, it is still harder to step in,  and it is still not an appropriate pattern. We obviously disagree which is fine. Different opinions are how we move the world forward.